# How to avoid nulling array in JSON with PoweShell

Tags: json, powershell

I working with JSON file:

```json
{
    "Job":  "abc",
    "Tasks":  [
                  {
                      "Task":  1
                  },
                  {
                      "Task":  2
                  }
              ]
}
```

and in some cases I have to remove all tasks and then my output JSON file looks like this:

```json
{
    "Job":  "abc",
    "Tasks": null
}
```

PowerShell code which I'm using to remove tasks below:

```
$Job = Get-Content -Path '.\Job.json'|ConvertFrom-Json
$Tasks = $Job.Tasks
$Tasks = $Tasks|Where-Object {$_.Task -ne 1}
$Tasks = $Tasks|Where-Object {$_.Task -ne 2}
$Job|ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 2|Out-File -Path '.\Job.json'
```

This JSON file is used by other tools and this **null** field causing issues.
I have tried to use **Array** and **ArrayList** but as far as I found PowerShell doesn't support **indexOf()** method so I don't know which item has to be removed.

Comment: Last line shouldn't it be $Tasks instead of $Job?  Tasks may be a singleton so it should be  @($Tasks) | ConvertTo-JSON...............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), whose purpose is exactly to ensure that a pipeline's collected output is *unconditionally* made an array - even if there is *no* or just *one* output object:

```
$job = Get-Content -Raw .\Job.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Use @(...) to ensure the output becomes an array.
$job.Tasks = @($job.Tasks | Where-Object { $_.Task -notin 1, 2 })

$job | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2 | Out-File .\Job.json
```

Note:

- Using `-Raw` with `Get-Content` is more efficient: it reads the entire file into a *single string*.
- A single `Where-Object` call is used, using a single logical operation based on [`-notin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin) operator.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found solution - it's not super clean but it's working

```
    $Job = Get-Content -Path '.\Job.json'|ConvertFrom-Json
    $Job.Tasks = $Job.Tasks|Where-Object {$_.Task -ne 1}
    $Job.Tasks = $Job.Tasks|Where-Object {$_.Task -ne 2}
    if(-not ($Job.Tasks)){
        $Job.Tasks = @()
    }
    else {
        $Job.Tasks = , $Job.Tasks
    }
    $Job|ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2|Out-File -FilePath '.\Job.json'
```